# Get onDrawerOpened and onDrawerClosed callbacks

Tags: android

My ActionBarDrawerToggle initialization

```
actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.drawer_opened, R.string.drawer_closed);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you provide a larger code sample? More details would help us answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

To get onDrawerOpened, onDrawerClosed and other utility methods to work you have to implement DrawerListener in your activity;

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DrawerListener {

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(View arg0, float arg1) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerStateChanged(int arg0) {

    }
}
```

Then you have to add this line to register the listener and receive callbacks:

```
actionBarDrawerToggle.addDrawerListener(this);
```